# Chromecast more than one video element

Tags: chromecast, google-cast

is it possible to play more than one video element at a time on Chromecast? Or at least to have two video elements and just play one of them?

I tried it but I just get a black screen for the second video. But there is no error while debugging.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have two active video elements at the same time. However, you can have two video elements but play in one, unload the media from that element, play in the second one, etc. Note that "pausing" is not adequate, you need to fully unload it from one before switching to the other one; for example, set `video.src=''` to destroy the video pipeline. I haven't tested that myself but if you run into issues with that approach, please let us know and we'll dig deeper.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately no. Thus we were not able to find good way to integrate ads via Google IMA SDK. It lead to bad user experience when IMA SDK need to "share" player with Video itself - there is always "blackout" at the end of ads playback till main video is loaded.